# get pixel value greyscale image 16 bits .net

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I have an ushort list `pixels16` which consist in pixeldata from a 16 bits greyscale image.
Then, I have a pícturebox that shows the image and a function where the user can click anywhere in the picturebox and the system will return the pixelvalue for that position (see below the code)

This is the code to return the pixel value of a given position: in my mind, I'm showing the value of the exact pixel the user clicked at a position in the image, am I right?

My logic is, if the image is 512x512, then I can go first by `Y` then once it finds the spot, go by `X` and get the pixel value of that point like this: `int pixelposition = (512 * (y-1)) + x;`

Am I in the right direction?

```
        for (int y = 0; y < picbox_mpr.Width; y++)
        {
            if (e.Y == y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < picbox_mpr.Height; x++)
                {
                    if (e.X == x)
                    {
                        int pixelposition = (512 * (y-1)) + x;
                        string a= pixels16[pixelposition].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not load the data into a 512x512 array of ushort?

Comment: pixels16 is an ushort array that contains the pixeldata..

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int y = 0; y < picbox_mpr.Width; y++)
>      {
>          if (e.Y == y)
>          {
>              for (int x = 0; x < picbox_mpr.Height; x++)
>              {
>                  if (e.X == x)
>                  {
> ```

Ah, yes, the [For-if](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx) pattern.

This should simply be turned into

```
int pixelposition = (512 * (e.Y-1)) + e.X;
string a= pixels16[pixelposition].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(a);
```

With no loops.

You should be aware that e.X and e.Y are based on where the mouse is on the screen relative to the top of the control, not relative to the image. It'll just be a little bit wrong in some modes due to margins, but if it's scrolled or scaled or centered it'll be very wrong. You should look at [this example code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20923/Mouse-Position-over-Image-in-a-PictureBox) for how to translate to image coordinates.

Comment: It worked like a charm without the For!
Now, when I click in the picturebox, I get 65536 in a black area, shouldn't I be getting 0?

Comment: @Matimont I have no idea what your image is, how you are loading it (including how you're putting it in the picture box), or whether you've dealt with the coordinate issues I mentioned. 65536, however, is an impossible value for a ushort, which are limited to 0..65535.